# Как узнать что это папка или файл javascript string

Tags: javascript

У меня есть переменная

```
let folder = "test"; //это папка
let file   = "test.js"; //это файл
let otherfolder = ".test_test-test" //это папка
```

Как сделать систему которая возращает это папка или файл

Comment: почему ".test_test-test" это папка а не файл?

Comment: Если суть в том, что файл- это строка с точкой не в начале строки, то это и проверяйте

Comment: Все упомянутые имена могут быть и у папок, и у файлов

Comment: Если этот вопрос относится к предыдущему про чтение файлов и папок с помощью nodejs, то можно проверить методами `.isFile()` или `.isDirectory()`. Подробности можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#file-system)

Comment: [fs.lstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630770/node-js-check-if-path-is-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что данный вопрос, это продолжение вопроса про [чтение списка файлов силами nodeJS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1518041/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-nodejs), то можно сделать так:

```
import fs from 'fs';

const option = {
  withFileTypes: true
}

fs.readdir('../.', option, (err, files) => {
  for (let file of files) {
    console.log(file.name, file.isFile() ? 'Файл' : 'Директория');
  }   
});
```

Читаем заданный каталог с опцией **withFileTypes: true**

В колбэк будет передан массив с указанием имени файла и типом. Проверяем тип с помощью метода **.isFile()**